# How to redirect people from Tumblr to random site?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, tumblr

I want to redirect people from my tumblr to another site, like example.com
But when I try to change HTML in tumblr theme adding http://example.com"> nothing is happen, only error.

Is there a way to redirect people? May be using javascript or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect in javascript.

If you want to keep the current page in the browser's history:

```
window.location.href = "https://example.com";
```

If you want to pretend the current page was just a 3xx-style redirect, and not have it in the browser's history:

```
window.location.replace("https://example.com");
```

That said, please keep in mind Tumblr's [Community Guidelines](https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/community), particularly the "Spam" section. Also, the [Terms of Service](https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/terms-of-service). Any redirect should be *expected*, from the point of view of the user, and not solely for the purpose of generating revenue.